# Making itertools.combinations calculations multiprocess in python?

Tags: python, decimal, multiprocessing, combinations, python-itertools

I'm using such algorithm to make some calculations on array of Decimals:

```
fkn = Decimal('0')
for bits in itertools.combinations(decimals_array, elements_count):
    kxn = reduce(operator.mul, bits, Decimal('1'))
    fkn += kxn
```

I'm using Python 3.4 x64.
**Decimals have precision>300 (it's a must)**.
len(decimals_array) is most of the time over 40. 
elements_count is most of the time len(decimals_array)/2.

**Calculations take very long time**.
I wanted to make them multiprocess so first I was thinking about making an array of all combinations and send parts of this array to many processes - but during making of such array I quickly get MemoryError Exception.

Now I'm looking for nicer way to make this code multiprocess.

**What is a good way to run this algorithm on multiple cores?**

Or maybe there is a better (faster) way to make such calculations?

Thank you in advance for some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

In order to really parallelize this you need to get around `combinations()` being sequential so that each process can generate its own combinations. The rest of the problem is already paralellizable.

40 choose 20 is about 138 billion combinations so pre-generating that or generating it in each process is going to hurt. With a 20-element list taking around 224 bytes (says `sys.getsizeof()`) that's 30 something terabytes if you generate the whole thing in one go. No wonder you ran out of memory. You also can't really split a generator across processes; or rather, if you do, each process will get its own copy of the generator.

Solution 1 is to have a process whose sole job is to generate combinations and push them into a queue, possibly in batches to save on IPC overhead, and have the other processes consume combinations from that queue.

Solution 2 is to write a non-sequential version of `combinations` that returns the Nth combination without computing the rest. This is definitely possible because it's possible with permutations, and combinations are an internally sorted subset of permutations. Then each process in a `Pool` can generate its own based on a start and step of N - process one counts combination `0, 3, 6...`, process two counts combination `1, 4, 7...` and so on, for example. This would probably be even slower unless you use C/Cython though.

Solution 3 (or possibly solution 0?) is to go over to the math stackexchange and ask if there's a mathematical rather than computational solution to this problem.

Comment: I will try to go with your Solution 2 but a little bit modified; I think I found solution how I can "split" generator across processes. In Python3 with help of pickle and itertools.islice is somehow possible. I will post my results when I make it done. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @vac did you succeed? Did you post the results?

Comment: @Deepstop I don't know if this is of any help for you but there is a function `binom_combi` at https://github.com/markpiffer/pypourri which allows to start from a selected combination, and it also features a special counting scheme where the single places between combinations never assume a > +/-1 position difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution although it isn't very neat.
The idea is to use multiple processes where one process is responsible for one `interval`. However, since `itertools.combinations` is sequential, each process has to loop over unnecessary combinations until it reaches the right interval. When the right interval is handled, the process stops. The code is from [this book](https://plink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_combo/).

```
import itertools
from tqdm import tqdm
from math import factorial
from multiprocessing import Process
import itertools

def total_combo(n, r):
    return factorial(n) // factorial(r) // factorial(n-r)


def cal_combo(var,noCombo,start,end):
    data = itertools.combinations(range(var),noCombo)
    for i in enumerate(tqdm(data)):
        if i[0] >= start:
            if i[0] < start+10: print(i)
            if i[0] > end: break

if __name__=='__main__':

    noCombo=3
    var=1000

    print(total_combo(var,noCombo),'combinations for',noCombo,'of',var,'variants')
    noProc=6
    interval=total_combo(var,noCombo)/noProc
    if interval%1==0:
        print(interval)

        procs=[]

        for pid in range(noProc):
            proc = Process(target=cal_combo, args=(var,noCombo, interval*pid, interval*(pid+1)))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()

        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
```